# How to read a specific part of a string?

Tags: lua

Essentially, what I need is to read a certain part of a string.

Example:

I have a string that contains "12 31".
However, I need to put these numbers into separate variables. Just sorts 12 into lets say variable A, and 31 in variable B.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Lua Patterns`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.htm):

```
> ExampleString = "12 31"
> ExampleString:match("(%d+)%s+(%d+)")
12      31
> SubString1, SubString2= ExampleString:match("(%d+)%s+(%d+)")
> Number1 = tonumber(SubString1)
> Number2 = tonumber(SubString2)
```

The `Pattern expression` seems complex but is actually quite simple. The things between `(` and `)` are named `captures` and will be returned if they are found. Here, we want 2 results so we have 2 couples `(` and `)`. `%d+` means that we want to find a string which contains at least 1 digit (`+`).

The 2 numbers are separated by some spaces `%s+`, at least 1 (`+`).

In summary, we want to extract (Number1)space(Number2)

The function [`string.match`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.match) is used to match against the given `pattern` and returns the found strings. The last step is to use the function [`tonumber`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-tonumber) to convert the found sub-strings into `Lua` numbers.

Comment: using `string` as a variable name is bad practice. those `( )` "things" in a Lua pattern are called captures btw.

Comment: I improved the answer based on your comment.